# Strange behaviour when threads using local var

Tags: c#

I wrote a simple code

```
void go()
{
    int i = 5;
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 1000; j++)
            Console.Write(i);
    });
    for (int k = 1; k <= 1000; k++)
        i = k;
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

What I got is : `100010001000100010001000....`

I don't know why, I hope someone can explain it to me, thanks!

Comment: What did you *expect* to see?

Comment: @Jon well, I expect to see different i's since it's changing

Comment: @cloudyFan: It should be obvious that since you are seeing 1000 and the only way that could have happened is for the `k` loop to have already completed, `i` is definitely *not* changing by the time it gets printed out. This happens because you have a race condition: if the OS schedules the delegate thread to run before the `k` loop completes you will see different behavior. An easy way to see that happening is to change `k <= 1000` to something like `k <= 10000000`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop that assigns `k` to `i` is run before the queued threads are being started.

So, at the time the queued threads are started, `i` has the value `1000` which is what you see.

Comment: Why? I think the new thread should start and begin write(i)?

Comment: Because the ThreadPool doesnt start the threads immediately http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: @cloudyFan, starting an operation on another thread isn't instantaneous; by the time it starts, the other loop is already complete, so the value of i is already 1000.

Answer (score 1):

Change the code to something like

```
    void go()
    {
        int i = 5;
        int i1 = i; //note this
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 1000; j++)
                Console.Write(i1); //and note this
        });
        for (int k = 1; k <= 1000; k++)
            i = k;
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

[Resharper reports "Access to modified closure".](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/Access+to+modified+closure)

Comment: shouldn't this get 55555555555555555555?